# Doctrine custom repository responsibilities

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm currently using ZF 2 with Doctrine 2. Right now I have a user service which I want to replace with a custom repository. This is working great so far, but I'm unsure whether I should also put methods that add/attach other entities to a user into this custom repository.
One example method that currently resides in the user service is this one:

```
public function addBookmark(User $user, $userId, $videoId)
{
    $author = $this->getById($userId);

    $bookmarkEntity = new Bookmark();
    $bookmarkEntity->setAuthor($author);
    $bookmarkEntity->setUser($user);
    $bookmarkEntity->setVideoId($videoId);

    $user->addBookmark($bookmarkEntity);

    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($bookmarkEntity);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

I think that this functionality would be too "custom" for the repository.

An alternative would be to put all find methods into the custom repository and let the remaining methods stay in the service, while injecting the repository. However, the disadvantage of that approach is that I can't access the entity manager in the user service from the repository directly, resulting in a second dependency (entity manager) only for persisting an flushing.

What would be the best approach? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you really want to flush at this stage? It will save all changes since your last flush, which means losing your transaction if you want to do more database actions after this function.

Comment: Thats not an issue, since it's the only database action I perform during this request. However, you're right - does doctrine "auto-flush" at the end of the php request?

Comment: I know, but since it is a public function in your repository you allow other processes to use it too and you don't know if during those requests (which may be created in the future) it will be the same. I'm just saying it is bad practice. Doctrine does by default not auto flush. Maybe you can configure it to do so, but by default it won't